# Jquery, Javascript fadeIn, fadeOut not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

`time_60_mod` in the code below counts from `0` infinity. I tried to add a `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` to it and it doesnt seem to work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="the_numbers">0</h1>

<script>
var output = $('h1');
var isPaused = false;
var time = 0;
var t = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(!isPaused) {
        time++;
        var time_60_mod = time % 60;
        document.getElementById('the_numbers').innerHTML = 
            Math.floor(time / 3600) % 24
            + ":" + Math.floor(time / 60) % 60
            + ":" + time_60_mod.fadeOut(500);
        time_60_mod.fadeIn(500);
    }
}, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `time_60_mod` is a number, and doesn't have `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` methods...

Answer (score 1):

fadeIn and fadeOut functions must be used on elements of the DOM, here you are trying to fadeIn or fadeOut a local variable (a number, not an element).
Try to put the seconds in a tag ("span" for example) in your HTML and then apply the functions on this tag, referencing it the same way you referenced "h1".
Of course you have to change the affectation of the text (...innerHTML) to include the new tag